# Where is this dust located on my sensor?

Tags: sensor, cleaning, dust

I have a really nasty looking piece of dust on my 550D's sensor, situated in the top right-hand corner of each image I take with anything higher than f/11. I am going to get a decent sensor cleaning kit, but I'd like to know **which corner of the sensor** should I focus on to get rid of this annoying particle?

In other words, does a lens flip the incoming light from left to right **and** turn it upside down? I think that's correct, so that means the answer in this diagram will be **A**, correct?

[image]

And before anyone asks - yes, I will clean the entire sensor while I'm in there, but this will help me focus on this particular (pun intended) problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

C is the correct answer.

Well, actually it's A if you look at the sensor *from the back*, but my
guess is that you will turn the camera around and access the sensor from
the front. So it's C.

Comment: An old photographer's bad habits -- not only do I still expect the back to open, I can't help flicking the advance lever that isn't there anymore. This should be the selected answer -- I'll flag mine for moderator action.

Comment: Thanks Edgar and Stan - I will switch my accepted answer. Much appreciated!

Comment: I didn't know you could do that -- I've never asked a question on SE, except on Meta where a definitive answer from one of the chief cooks and/or bottle-washers was provided. (You don't not accept a policy explanation from Jeff.)