# Why do photos with different settings produce different spots?

Tags: lens, nikon, sensor

I have an issue with my Nikon D3500 camera which I do not understand. I can show it best using two photos I took with different settings. The lens I use is a kit lens which ranges from 18 to 105 mm.

This is photo #1: it has an F-number f/29, an exposure time of 1/160, and a focal length of 34 mm.

[image]

<sup>Image resized. Click the image to view in full size (6000x4000)</sup>

From photo #1 you can clearly see there are small black spots on the picture that should not be there. So I thought that it must be an issue with the sensor of the camera and I need to go get it cleaned.

However, here is photo #2 (the same scene with different settings): it has an F-number f/4.2, an exposure time of 1/4000, and a focal length of 34 mm.

[image]

<sup>Image resized. Click the image to view in full size (6000x4000)</sup>

In photo #2 you can see that the spots seen in photo #1 are no longer there. For context, I took these two photos in Aperture priority mode, so the only setting I changed was the F-number.

This pattern, where the greater the F-number, the clearer the spots on the photo is something which I have consistently noticed in all my photos. So my question is, what could be the issue with my camera where these spots appear at only large F-numbers?

Comment: Thanks for asking this!!  I had the same issue and just assumed I hadn't cleaned the lens off or something.  Learn something new every day!

Comment: If you want to see *all* the dust on your sensor, take a f/1000 picture - use a small light source like a bright LED, shining on the sensor from across a dark room, with no lens on the camera. Mine looked like a petri dish!

Comment: Also related: [What is the best way to clean the sensor on a interchangeable lens camera (mirrorless or digital SLR)?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/12/15871) and [Why are these black dots / spots appearing in my pictures?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/41939/15871) and [Is this dust on lens or something else?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/102811/15871) and [Dust on Sensor After Many Cleanings DSLR](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/102253/15871)

Answer (score 40):

Let me just complement Xenoid's answer.

In this diagram, you can see how a bigger aperture produces a diffused shadow, that sometimes is hard to see.

And when you use a smaller aperture, the shadow of the dust is more visible.

[image]

Answer (score 23):

This is typical of sensor dust, the spots are more visible at small apertures. In fact taking a picture of the sky with a small aperture (large f-number) is the usual way to check for dust spots...

So you just need to clean your sensor.

You camera likely has a way to shake the dust off the sensor on command, or automatically when starting up or shutting down.

If these are not enough, blowing some air (with a bulb blower, not breath or compressed air) on the sensor usually works (remove the lens, and lock the mirror up to see the sensor, your camera must have an option for this).

[image]

You'll find more information on cleaning you sensor [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/12/9161).

You can also ask a professional to do this for approximately 25 dollar/pound/euros.

Comment: Sensor cleaning 25 $/£/€ seems a bit optimistic.  I paid £30 in 2018 and €40 in 2022.

Comment: And if blowing fails, you can buy cleaning kits - I have previously used something that looks like a tiny squeegee to sweep over the sensor

Comment: Is there a clue that tells you these are from dust on the sensor as opposed to dust on the lens or the mirror?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy There is no mirror in the optical path when the picture is taken, so dust on mirror only shows in the viewfinder. Dust in lens is hardly visible (unless it's the front lens and you are doing extreme macro), usually it just makes the pictures lose a bit of contrast.